# Java un-maximize JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a simple question that I have not found an answer two, possibly because I do not know how to title it. Lets say I have a JFrame with width X and height Y. Somewhere in my program I must maximize it to fit to take up the whole screen, and do `myJFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);` to accomplish that. Now, somewhere later I must make the JFrame "un-maximize" and return to its original size. There is probably a simple command for this but i have not found any. I have in mind a command akin to something like `myJFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_NONE);`
So in short: after maximizing a JFrame, how do I "un-maximize" it?

**Edit:** It seems that the problem was not that i was not able to find the method i neaded, but that some of my code was preventing `myJFrame.setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);` from working correctly. Here is this buggy code:

```
        frame.dispose();
        if (b) {
            frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            frame.setUndecorated(true);
        } else {
            frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
            frame.setUndecorated(false);
        }
        frame.setVisible(true);
```

Rearranging the statements in the above code fixed the problem :)

Comment: You seem to have an idea, have you tried it?

Comment: I have tried both 'frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);' and 'frame.setState(JFrame.NORMAL);' , but neither seem to work. And 'MAXIMIZED_NONE' isnt actually a constant.

Comment: Can you provide me with a runnable example which demonstrates `JFrame.NORMAL` not working, because my test worked fine

Comment: I have a lot of code that forms a big game library. But the code in question is this: http://pastebin.com/VRTXH13d it is part of a method to make the JFrame fullscreen/ not fullscreen. 'b' is the parameter. If 'b' is true the JFrame is extended else it must be put to its original size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at the JavaDocs for [`Frame#setExtendedState`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState(int)), you will see a list of possible values

> Sets the state of this frame. The state is represented as a bitwise
>   mask.
>    - NORMAL 
>     Indicates that no state bits are set.
>    - ICONIFIED
>    - MAXIMIZED_HORIZ
>    - MAXIMIZED_VERT
>    - MAXIMIZED_BOTH
>      Concatenates MAXIMIZED_HORIZ and MAXIMIZED_VERT.

Then if we have a look at [`Frame#NORMAL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#NORMAL)

> Frame is in the "normal" state. This symbolic constant names a frame state with all state bits cleared

That seems promising

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {

            JButton unmax = new JButton("Switch");
            unmax.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JFrame frame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(TestPane.this);
                    if (frame.getExtendedState() != JFrame.NORMAL) {
                        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
                    } else {
                        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
                    }
                }
            });
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            add(unmax);

        }

    }

}
```

So, all this does, is checks the current windows `extendedState`, if it's not set to `NORMAL`, it sets it to `NORMAL`, otherwise it sets it to `MAXIMIZED_BOTH`

## Updated based on example code...

Okay, so based on your example code...

```
frame.dispose();
if (b) {
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setUndecorated(true);
} else {
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
    frame.setUndecorated(false);
}
frame.setVisible(true);
```

The problem "seems" to lie with either `dispose` or `setUndecorated` or a combination of both.  What "seems" to happening is when you restore the frame to it's normal state, it's maintaining the size and position it was when it was maximized.

So, what I did, was grab a copy of the windows `bounds` before it was maximised and when it was restored, I reapplied it

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    private Rectangle previousBounds;

    public TestPane() {

        JButton unmax = new JButton("Switch");
        unmax.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFrame frame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(TestPane.this);
                frame.dispose();
                if (frame.getExtendedState() != JFrame.NORMAL) {
                    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
                    frame.setUndecorated(false);
                    frame.setBounds(previousBounds);
                } else {
                    previousBounds = frame.getBounds();
                    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
                    frame.setUndecorated(true);
                }
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        add(unmax);

    }

}
```

Comment: This is weird. Your code works but mice does not.Do you think the frame being disposed of prevents it from un-maximizing?

Comment: It seems to be a combination of `dispose` and `setUndecorated` (and possibly `setExtendedState`), see update

Comment: Alright, I guess the problem was with my code and not me not being able to find a method.

Comment: one plus, :-) seems you are ignore a JToggleButton

Comment: @mKorbel Yeah, that might have been easier :P